# Button Enabled and disabled using MVVMLight in xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin.android

Actually what I want is I want my button disabled and not clickable when edit text field is empty but when some one type in that edit text field button becomes enabled.
I already tried -

```
android:clickable = "false"
android:enabled = "false"
```

But it's not working in my case and I do not know why
I am working on MVVM Light xamarin.Android project.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569).

Comment: @Dhanshri Please read [When should code formatting be used for non-code text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254995/6296561)

Comment: I alredy remove ASAP

Comment: No, [I did](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55238923/revisions). I left the comment to let you know you shouldn't add that in the first place.

Comment: Ok when u say then i remove that in the second place

Comment: But still got that no reply of my question

Comment: You can show xaml code and c# code about how to set button enable and disable.